# converting gcc inline assembly to ml64

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, visual-c++

As part of attempting to implement msvc support for cgo, I found that I needed to port some inline gcc assembly to ml64. Here is the original assembly:

```
ts = *(ThreadStart*)v;

/*
 * Set specific keys in thread local storage.
 */
__asm {
      "movq %0, %%gs:0x28\n"    // MOVL tls0, 0x28(GS)
      "movq %%gs:0x28, %%rax\n" // MOVQ 0x28(GS), tmp
      "movq %1, 0(%%rax)\n" // MOVQ g, 0(GS)
      :: "r"(ts.tls), "r"(ts.g) : "%rax"
}
```

And here is the external assembler file that I have created:

```
PUBLIC msvc_windows_amd64_threadentry

.CODE
    msvc_windows_amd64_threadentry PROC

        MOV gs:[0x28], ts.tls
        MOV rax, gs:[0x28]
        MOV gs:[0], ts.g

        ret
    msvc_windows_amd64_threadentry ENDP
END
```

Obviously there are some problems. For one, I have no idea at this time how to let the assembler know the structure of `ts`; gcc obviously knows about it because it's in the file that is being compiled but msvc doesn't support amd64 inline assembly. Another is I think that I will just be able to call `msvc_windows_amd64_threadentry` just like any other `extern` function, but I am not completely sure. Honestly I have never had to deal with assembly much so I've never had these problems before.

Comment: The main problem you have is that this is for linux thread local storage.  Windows thread local storage is completely different, so even if you could get that assembly to work with your compiler, it would not run on windows.

Comment: Depends entirely on what you are trying to do.  Rewrite the code to use `thread_local` if you don't mind being dependent on C11.

Comment: The inline assembly in your "original assembly" example is unnecessarily complex. Only the first assembly statement needs to be in inline assembly, the last two statements could've been coded in plain C. The third statement also don't match the comment given on the same line.

Comment: Actually, to clarify, when I said "gcc" I meant MinGW, and it seems that GS is used for thread local storage on win_amd64. Are you sure that this wouldn't operate correctly on windows? I don't think MinGW would be advanced enough to rewrite assembly.

Comment: Do you know whether the original code actually works on Windows?  It looks like whoever wrote it didn't quite know what they were doing.

Comment: @RossRidge I mean it's supposedly written by Google's finest. I'm just trying to port it.

Comment: And yes it does work with the MinGW (gcc) compiler.

Comment: Here's the full version: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/cgo/gcc_windows_amd64.c 

I of course truncated it to limit the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use assembly at all to port this code to Microsoft C++. You can use the [`__writegsqword`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/529bay7a.aspx) intrinsic to replace the first assembly instruction and then use plain C to replace the last two assembly instructions. For example:

```
__writegsqword(0x28, (unsigned long long) ts.tls);
*(void **)ts.tls = (void *) ts.g;
```

Note that depending on the types of `ts.tls` and `ts.g` you might be better off with different casts or can avoid them altogether.

You can use the same code with GCC and Microsoft C++ by adding a function like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
static inline void
__writegsqword(unsigned long long offset, unsigned long long value) {
    asm("movq %0,%%gs:%1" :: "re" (value), "m" (*(int *)offset));
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this. I was not looking forward to managing external assembly files.